# Setting Priority in Thread scheduler for threads which have waited and notified

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, thread-synchronization

I have a series of producer and consumer threads. In consumer thread I have `lock.wait()` function to stop execution if there is no data in queue. When data is produced in producer thread, `lock.notify()` is called and consumer thread comes out of waiting state and moved to thread scheduler for acquiring the lock. When the notifier producer thread releases the lock, thread scheduler selects a random thread for processing(which can also be a another producer thread but I want it to give lock to this waited thread). My problem is, is there a way for these waited and notified threads to get higher priority to acquire the lock soon instead of Thread scheduler treating as a normal thread. I have tried `Thread.currentthread.setPriority` and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Highest priority thread will always get the CPU time is not guaranteed. The JVM may choose to run a lower priority thread at times.

Check out this link http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/threads/priority.html